# How to expand \cases in Lyx when using \sum?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, cases

I need to write a case differentiation in LyX which contains sums but here is the problem.

This

```
A=\begin{cases}
-\sum_{j\text{=1}}^{N}a_{j}^{(1)} & \text{}\\
-\sum_{j\text{=1}}^{N}a_{j}^{(2)}
\end{cases}
```

gives that

[image]

But I want that indices of sum would be over the sum like this:

[image]

How to do that?

Comment: you could use `\displaystyle -\sum....`  But note `\text{=1}` is wrong the =1 should be in math mode not text mode

Comment: The package `mathtools` provides the `dcases` environment for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LyX, put the cursor just to the right of sigma (but before the limits). Then either type the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>; or go to Edit > Math > Change Limits Type > Display.

Comment: This seems to work fine! Thank you @scottkosty